# SRPGの移動と攻撃範囲を同時に表示させたい

Tags: unity3d, game-development

現在、ファイアーエムブレム風の3DSRPGを制作しています。
Unityを触り始めて間もないということもあり、現在おそらく本プロジェクトの一番の壁にぶち当たっております。

以下の記事を参考に移動範囲を表示させることに成功しました。

[シミュレーションゲームにおける移動範囲を求めるアルゴリズム - Qiita](https://qiita.com/y244/items/5e769d497a370fac2e0e)

しかし、キャラクターの移動範囲と攻撃範囲を同時に表示させることが叶わず、頭をひねっております。

マップの大きさをテレインの大きさ、キャラやマップオブジェクトの座標を `ofset = 10;`
`Positionvol.massxValue` は20です。キャラやマップオブジェクトの位置を10+20の倍率で座標を設定しています。1マスの大きさは20です。
あらかじめキャラの移動範囲と武器の射程を足し合わせ、そこからSearchの条件分岐でうまくいくかと思ったのですが、近くにあるマップオブジェクト(移動コスト-99)にも攻撃範囲が表示されてしまいます。

長くなりましたが、なにかほかに共有してほしい情報や、至らない点がありましたらお教えください。

移動範囲を表示させる現状のコードは以下の通りです。

```
// 移動コスト
int[,] _originalMapList;
// 移動計算結果のデータ格納用
int[,] _resultMoveRangeList;


// マップ上のx,z位置
int _x;
int _z;
// 移動力
int _m;

// マップの大きさ
int _xLength;
int _zLength;
int ofset = Positon.massxValue/2;

public void SetMoveCost(MapObject[,] mapObjects)
{
    _xLength = (int)Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.size.x;
    _zLength = (int)Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.size.z;

    _originalMapList = new int[_xLength, _zLength];
    _resultMoveRangeList = new int[_xLength, _zLength];

    // 移動コストのマップデータ(\orizinalMapList)を作成 (本来はここでは作成せず外部から渡す)
    for (int i = ofset; i < _xLength; i += Positionvol.massxVolue)
    {
        for (int j = ofset; j < _zLength; j += Positionvol.masszVolue)
        {
            _originalMapList[i, j] = mapObjects[i, j].Cost;
        }
    }
}

void Copy()
{
    for (int i = ofset; i < _xLength; i += Positionvol.massxVolue)
    {
        for (int j = ofset; j < _zLength; j += Positionvol.masszVolue)
        {
            // 適切な条件でループを終了する
            if (i < _xLength && j < _zLength)
            {
                _resultMoveRangeList[i, j] = _originalMapList[i, j];
            }
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// 探索開始
/// 計算結果のマップデータを返す
/// </summary>
public int[,] StartSearch(int currentX, int currentZ, int movePower,int range)
{
    Copy();

    _xLength = _resultMoveRangeList.GetLength(0);
    _zLength = _resultMoveRangeList.GetLength(1);

    _x = currentX;
    _z = currentZ;
    _m = movePower;

    // 現在位置に現在の移動力を代入
    _resultMoveRangeList[_x, _z] = _m;
    Search4(_x, _z, _m, range);

    return _resultMoveRangeList;
}


/// <summary>
/// 移動可能な範囲の4方向を調べる
/// </summary>
void Search4(int x, int z, int m,int range)
{

    if (0 < x && x < _xLength && 0 < z && z < _zLength)
    {
        // 上方向
        Search(x, z - Positionvol.massxVolue, m,range);
        // 下方向
        Search(x, z + Positionvol.masszVolue, m,range);
        // 左方向
        Search(x -Positionvol.massxVolue, z, m,range);
        // 右方向
        Search(x + Positionvol.masszVolue, z, m, range);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// 移動先のセルの調査
/// </summary>
void Search(int x, int z, int m,int range)
{
    // 探索方向のCellがマップエリア領域内かチェック
    if (x < 0 || _xLength <= x) return;
    if (z < 0 || _zLength <= z) return;

    // すでに計算済みのCellかチェック
    if ((m - 1) <= _resultMoveRangeList[x, z]) return;

    //もし武器攻撃範囲より上なら現在の移動可能量　+ 地形コスト
    if (m >= range)
    {
            m = m + _originalMapList[x, z];
     if (m <= -80)
        {
            m = range;
        }
        
    }
    //武器の攻撃範囲より下なら-1
    else
    {
        m= -1;
    }
  

    if (m > 0)
    {
        // 進んだ位置に現在の移動力を代入
        _resultMoveRangeList[x, z] = m;
        // 移動量があるのでSearch4を再帰呼びだし

        Search4(x, z, m,range);
    }
    else
    {
        m = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 「移動と同時に」でなければ「攻撃範囲」単体では表示させることができているのでしょうか。